# How to calculate the time difference between two locations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimezone

I am having a problem with calculating time difference between two timeZones.

If I am at location A I know the latitude and longitude and the current time.
I go to location B I know the latitude and longitude and the current time.

How to calculate the time difference between the two current points .. (in UTC)

Comment: Just subtract the the current time in location A from current time in location B. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yep, he wants to do it by longitude and latitud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly get a database or library that converts lat/long to get the country and state/province. Then use the NSTimeZone class to retrieve the timezone for a particular country. You can purchase such databases from many sites, ie:
     http://www.ip2location.com/

To do the actual conversion you would do something like this:

```
NSTimeZone *sourceTimeZone =
    [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"GMT"];
NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone =
    [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"EST"];

NSInteger sourceSeconds =
    [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger destinationSeconds =
    [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationSeconds - sourceSeconds;
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur answer ..
I mean i did this way with the timeZone..

NSTimeZone *sourceTimeZone =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"America/Menominee"]];
 NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"America/Juneau"]];
 
 NSDate *date1=[NSDate date];
 NSInteger sourceSeconds = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date1];
 NSInteger destinationSeconds =[destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date1];
 NSTimeInterval interval = destinationSeconds - sourceSeconds;

Thanks again

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the day time and the night time at that location

Comment: because the at each place the sunset and the sunrise time will be different http://www.mindspring.com/~cavu/sunset.html i have got this form where we cn actually find out the difference and all but dont know how to implement it :(

Comment: A long time ago i did see some code online that calculates the sunrise/sunset based on longitude and latitude. Im sure you can find it if you look on google.

Comment: There you go i found it (: http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm