# Get Place Location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

I need put information about place, where is iPhone now, to UILable in my screen. [Country][City][Street] and maybe coordinates [lat][lng]. For example in my UILable should be:

Your location is German, Berlin, Tiergarten

Can someone show me really simple code how can i get such information that put in my UILable?

Comment: This is a fairly close duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470870/how-to-calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-locations/1471627#1471627

Answer (score 2):

The MapKit framework (part of iPhone OS 3.0) provides this for you. Specifically the MKPlacemark object, which you can obtain for a set of co-ordinates using an MKReverseGeocoder.

Answer (score 0):

You need access to a reverse geocoding service, which will take your lat/lon coordinates as input and return some kind of structured address of that location.

Google's is available here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#ReverseGeocoding